# What happened in the 4/5/2011 Team Fortress 2 update?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I just downloaded an update to Team Fortress 2. When I click on "details" however...

> Product Update     - Valve 15:11 Team
> Fortress 2
>
> - [ restricted ]

So... what does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/April_5,_2011_Patch), here's what was found:

> **Undocumented changes**
>
> - Added the [[ classified ]](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Classified)
> - Updated Magnanimous Monarch texture file.
> - Updated stock maps with AI movement information.
> - Turned Quality of some Vintage Lugermorphs to Unique in player's backpacks.
> - Changed levels of some items in player's backpacks.

The [ classified ] is really the [Potato Hat](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Potato_hat/factual). The file diff at the bottom of the page doesn't seem to reveal anything but the aforementioned changes (mainly the addition of the Potato Hat, the changes above were probably based on what was found in the diff).

There's a new post [on the blog](http://www.teamfortress.com/post.php?id=5223&p=1) but it's merely an aggregation of some community updates.

So there must be some sort of surprise... or could it *be* the Potato Hat after all?

Comment: I wasn't aware that Magnanimous Monarch was updated.  I don't recall seeing any of its texture files updated on my TF2 server... TF2 server updates tell you every file that changed, and the majority of the files were models for the Potato Hat.

Comment: @Powerlord: Fixed, I looked at the file name and it *is* the Potato Hat... my bad.

Comment: It's all related to Valve's latest (presumably Portal 2 themed) ARG: http://valvearg.info/wiki/Valve_ARG_Wiki